# SAS: How to use a where statement on a formatted variable?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm working with two datasets to which I've made many changes and alterations.
One of the main ones is changing the dates on the dataset to a Jan09 (monyy) format. 
With the first dataset I used and intck format to change it. And with the second one I created a macrovariable.

My issue is, I now want to isolate results according to particular months, but everytime I use `where month = 'Jan09'` f.e. I get an error saying the variable does not exist.

Does anyone know how I can use the where statement in this context?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Attach how you converted it into monyy5., Also. that is just a format, you r date is still stored as a whole date.

Comment: run proc contents on the dataset and make sure you have a variable called month.  If the error is saying variable does not exist it is not a format issue

Comment: What is the type num/char and format of the variable that you want to filter on? And what is the f.e. that you have in your question? Is that in your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the format of a date valued variable does not change the underlying value.

Try either of these

```
where put(<date-variable>, yymon7.) = '2009JAN';
where intck ('month', <date-variable>, '01-JAN-2009'D) = 0;
```

If you had *created* a new variable that contains the formatted value then it would be ok to use the formatted value in the where clause

```
data …
  set …
  <month-variable> = put (<date-variable>, yymon.);
run;

proc what-ever data=have;
  where <month-variable> = '2009JAN';
  …
```

Comment: You don't need to have the date in date9 format for the intck function?

Comment: Ill fix that typo

Answer (score 0):

If its a SAS date you have several options, but one is that the underlying dates are still stored. Assuming it's a SAS date and the name is myDate:

```
where myDate between '01Jan2009'd and '31Jan2009'd;
```

Obviously this isn't great because you have to know the end of the month.

Another option is to use the month/year to filter it out:

```
where month(myDate) = 1 and year(myDate) = 2009;
```

And yet another is to convert it to text and do a text comparison:

```
where put(myDate, monyy5.) = 'JAN09'; *case sensitive here;
```

Note that SAS summary procedures honour a format so that if you're trying to do summaries by month, including the date in a CLASS or BY variable will work as expected, but PROC SQL does not summarize data using a formatted variable.